# How to change fontsize of text inside a table?

Tags: tables

Well, this is my code and output (below) and i want to know if this possible to change, let's say, to 10pt the text size.

```
\begin{quadro}[H]
\caption{\textbf{Literatura internacional pertinente ao tema.}}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\columnwidth,center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Autor e ano} &
  \textbf{Método} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Recorte espacial e\\ temporal\end{tabular}} &
  \textbf{Insumos} &
  \textbf{Produtos} \\ \hline
Thanassoulis (1995) &
  DEA-CCR. &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}41 unidades policiais\\ da Inglaterra e do País\\ de Gales, (1992-1993).\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}N° de policias\\ empregados; n° de\\ crimes violentos;\\ roubos; outros crimes.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Taxa de esclarecimentos de\\ crimes violentos; taxa\\ de esclarecimentos de\\ roubos; taxa de\\ esclarecimentos de\\ outros crimes\\ registrados.\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Carrington et. al.\\ (1997)\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DEA-CCR e DEA-BCC. Modelo de dois\\ estágios com modelo\\ Tobit.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}163 unidades policiais\\ em Nova Gales do\\ Sul, Austrália, (1994-\\ 1995).\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}N° de policiais; n° de\\ voluntários civis; n°\\ de viaturas policiais.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}N° de crimes; n° de prisões; n° de\\ intimações; n° de\\ acidentes de carros\\ graves; Km’s\\ percorridos pelas\\ viaturas policias.\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Drake e Simper\\ (2000)\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DEA e análise\\ múltipla\\ discriminante.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Forças policiais\\ metropolitana da\\ Inglaterra e de Gales,\\ (1992-1997).\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Custo de emprego; despesas relacionadas\\ a instalações; despesas\\ relacionadas a\\ transporte; custos de\\ capital.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Taxa de esclarecimento; o nº\\ total de crimes de\\ tráfico; nº de testes de\\ bafômetro realizados.\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Drake e Simper\\ (2001)\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DEA (eficiência geral, \\ eficiência técnica e eficiência de escala).\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}39 Unidades Policiais\\ da Inglaterra e País de\\ Gales (1996-1999).\end{tabular} &
  Os mesmos de Drake e Simper (2000). &
  Os mesmos de Drake e Simper (2000). \\ \hline
Sun (2002) &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DEA. No segundo\\ estágio, múltiplas\\ regressões para\\ empregar uma análise\\ dos fatores externos.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}14 delegacias\\ municipais de Taipei,\\ Taiwan (1994-1996).\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Nº policiais; roubos; nº crimes violentos;\\ outros crimes.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Esclarecimentos de roubos; \\ esclarecimentos de\\ crimes violentos;\\ esclarecimentos de\\ outros crimes.\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Diez-Ticio e\\ Mancebon\\ (2002)\end{tabular} &
  DEA-BCC e modelo TMM. &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}47 Unidades Policiais\\ da Espanha (1995).\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Nº de policiais; Nº de veículos; Inverso\\ da População.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Taxa de esclarecimento de crimes\\  contra a propriedade; \\ taxa de esclarecimento de crimes violents .\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Drake e Simper\\ (2003)\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DEA-CCR, SFA, \\ SDEA e modelo Tobit no segundo estágio.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}42 Unidades Policiais\\ da Inglaterra e País de\\ Gales (1996-1999).\end{tabular} &
  Os mesmos de Drake e Simper (2000). &
  Os mesmos de Drake e Simper (2000). \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Barros e Alves\\ (2005)\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}SFA (Custo), com\\ controle para variáveis\\ ambientais.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}33 Delegacias de\\ Lisboa (1999-2003).\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Custo Operacional; fator Trabalho\\ (razão salário-trabalhadores); fator Capital 1\\ (razão custo de trasnportes-n º carros); fator\\ capital 2 (razão custo das instalações -população).\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}esclarecimentocrimes de \\ roubos e furtos;\\ esclarecimento de roubos\\  e furtos de veículos; \\  esclarecimentode crimes\\ envolvendo drogas.\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Drake e Simper\\ (2005)\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DEA-BCC e\\  Fronteira de distância de produto estocástica.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}293 Distritos Policiais\\ da Inglaterra e Paíse de\\ Gales (2001-2002).\end{tabular} &
  6 tipos de crimes diferentes. &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Esclarecimentos de 6 tipos de\\  crimes diferentes.\end{tabular} \\ \hline
Barros (2006) &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DEA-BCC com cálculo de\\ Índices de Malmquist.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}33 Delegacias de\\ Lisboa (2000-2002).\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Nº de policiais; Custo do trabalho; nº\\ de veículos; outros custos; roubos;\\ furtos; roubos de veículos; e crimes\\ relacionados a drogas.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Esclarecimento de roubos e furtos; \\ esclarecimentode roubos de \\ veículos;  esclarecimento\\ de crimes envolvendo drogas; \\ Operaçõesde Busca;\\  operações de trânsito e multas.\end{tabular} \\ \hline
Barros (2007) &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DEA-BCC, DEA-CCR e Modelo Tobit no\\ 2º Estágio.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Os mesmos de Barros\\ (2006).\end{tabular} &
  Os mesmos de Barros (2006). &
  Os mesmos de Barros (2006). \\ \hline
Gárcia-Sánchez (2007) &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DEA-CCR e modelo \\ Tobit no segundo estágio.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}52 capitais provinciais na Espanha\\ (1999).\end{tabular} &
  Crimes e delitos leves. &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Número de indivíduos\\  presos em crimes;\\ número de indivíduos \\ presos em delitos leves\end{tabular} \\ \hline
Gárcia-Sánchez (2009) &
  DEA-BCC. &
  113 cidades na Espanha (2000). &
  Total de funcionários e nº de veículos. &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Segurança pública;\\ Segurança na estrada.\end{tabular} \\ \hline
Gárcia-Sánchez et. al. (2013) &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DEA-BCC com cálculo de\\ Índices de Malmquist.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Unidades policiais de províncias na Espanha \\ (2001-2006).\end{tabular} &
  Nº de forças de seguranças por província. &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Nº de crimes solucionados \\ sobre de crimes;\\ crimes contra pessoas; \\ crimes contra a liberdade sexual; \\ crimes contra a segurança pública.\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Haddad et. al.\\ (2013)\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DEA-CCR regressão no 2º\\ Estágio (fatores exógenos).\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}13 delegacias no sul\\ de Israel, (2008-2011).\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}nsumos de crimes;\\ insumos operacionais;\\ e insumos regionais.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Taxa anual de\\ esclarecimentos de\\ crimes contra a\\ propriedade; nº de\\ casos envolvendo\\ embriaguez\\ esclarecidos; nº\\ relatórios de tráfego.\end{tabular} \\ \hline
Poveda et. al. (2019) &
  DEA e GMM. &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}20 departamentos na Colombia\\ (2001-2015).\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Nível de educação;\\ nº de criminosos presos; \\ nº de policiais.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Taxa de homicídios;\\ nível de corrupção.\end{tabular} \\ \hline
Alda et. al. (2020) &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Modelo fronteira\\ parcial de ordem m,\\ condicional e\\ incondicional.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}1634 forças policiais\\ municipais no\\ México, (2015).\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Nº de policiais; nº de\\ viaturas policiais;\\ tecnologia disponível.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Nº de crimes\\ impedidos\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\fonte{Elaboração do autor a partir dos estudos citados.}
\label{quad:quadro}
\end{quadro}
```

Output:part of table
[image]

Comment: don't do `\begin{adjustbox}{width=\columnwidth,center}`  if you scale the table you lose control  over the fonts and rule widths and are bound to get sizes inconsistent with the rest of the document. Choose a sensible size like `\small` or if you must, `\footnotesize` then arrange the column text to fit.

Comment: Remove the `adjustbox` command around the `tabular` since rescaling tables leads to inconsistent fonte sizes, as you just discovered. To change the font size of all contents of a `tabular`, you can use commands such as `\small` right before `\begin{tabular}`.

Comment: @leandriis excellent comment:-)

Comment: @davidCarlise, first, thanks for the answer. I excluded adjustbox, but i lost the control of table, its off the page now. How to fix this?

Comment: Thank you @leandriis : )

Comment: @VitorDeVasconcelosLima: If you want your table to use a readable font size, you will most likely not be able to squeeze it onto a single page. I would use a `longtable` or `xltabular` and spread the whole table over multiple landscape orented pages.

Comment: try some of the suggestion in this duplicate question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options

Comment: Again, thank you sir !!

Answer (score 1):

The following might help getting you started:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}|X|X|X|X|}
\caption{Literatura internacional pertinente ao tema.}\label{quad:quadro}\\
\hline
\textbf{Autor e ano} &
  \textbf{Método} &
  \textbf{Recorte espacial e temporal} &
  \textbf{Insumos} &
  \textbf{Produtos}  \\ \hline
  \endfirsthead
 \caption{Literatura internacional pertinente ao tema. - continuead from previous page}\\
\hline
\textbf{Autor e ano} &
  \textbf{Método} &
  \textbf{Recorte espacial e temporal} &
  \textbf{Insumos} &
  \textbf{Produtos}  \\ \hline
  \endhead 
Thanassoulis (1995) &
  DEA-CCR. &
  41 unidades policiais da Inglaterra e do País de Gales, (1992-1993). &
  N° de policias empregados; n° de crimes violentos; roubos; outros crimes. &
  Taxa de esclarecimentos de crimes violentos; taxa de esclarecimentos de roubos; taxa de esclarecimentos de outros crimes registrados.  \\ \hline
Carrington et. al. (1997) &
  DEA-CCR e DEA-BCC. Modelo de dois estágios com modelo Tobit. &
  163 unidades policiais em Nova Gales do Sul, Austrália, (1994- 1995). &
  N° de policiais; n° de voluntários civis; n° de viaturas policiais. &
  N° de crimes; n° de prisões; n° de intimações; n° de acidentes de carros graves; Km’s percorridos pelas viaturas policias.  \\ \hline
Drake e Simper (2000)&
  DEA e análise múltipla discriminante. &
  Forças policiais metropolitana da Inglaterra e de Gales, (1992-1997). &
  Custo de emprego; despesas relacionadas a instalações; despesas relacionadas a transporte; custos de capital.  &
  Taxa de esclarecimento; o nº total de crimes de tráfico; nº de testes de bafômetro realizados.  \\ \hline
Drake e Simper (2001) &
  DEA (eficiência geral,  eficiência técnica e eficiência de escala). &
  39 Unidades Policiais da Inglaterra e País de Gales (1996-1999). &
  Os mesmos de Drake e Simper (2000). &
  Os mesmos de Drake e Simper (2000).  \\ \hline
Sun (2002) &
  DEA. No segundo estágio, múltiplas regressões para empregar uma análise dos fatores externos. &
  14 delegacias municipais de Taipei, Taiwan (1994-1996). &
  Nº policiais; roubos; nº crimes violentos; outros crimes. &
  Esclarecimentos de roubos;  esclarecimentos de crimes violentos; esclarecimentos de outros crimes.  \\ \hline
Diez-Ticio e Mancebon (2002) &
  DEA-BCC e modelo TMM. &
  47 Unidades Policiais da Espanha (1995). &
  Nº de policiais; Nº de veículos; Inverso da População. &
  Taxa de esclarecimento de crimes  contra a propriedade;  taxa de esclarecimento de crimes violents .  \\ \hline
Drake e Simper (2003) &
  DEA-CCR, SFA,  SDEA e modelo Tobit no segundo estágio. &
  42 Unidades Policiais da Inglaterra e País de Gales (1996-1999). &
  Os mesmos de Drake e Simper (2000). &
  Os mesmos de Drake e Simper (2000).  \\ \hline
Barros e Alves (2005) &
  SFA (Custo), com controle para variáveis ambientais. &
  33 Delegacias de Lisboa (1999-2003). &
  Custo Operacional; fator Trabalho (razão salário-trabalhadores); fator Capital 1 (razão custo de trasnportes-n º carros); fator capital 2 (razão custo das instalações -população). &
  esclarecimentocrimes de roubos e furtos; esclarecimento de roubos  e furtos de veículos;   esclarecimentode crimes envolvendo drogas.  \\ \hline
Drake e Simper (2005) &
  DEA-BCC e  Fronteira de distância de produto estocástica. &
  293 Distritos Policiais da Inglaterra e Paíse de Gales (2001-2002). &
  6 tipos de crimes diferentes. &
  Esclarecimentos de 6 tipos de  crimes diferentes.  \\ \hline
Barros (2006) &
  DEA-BCC com cálculo de Índices de Malmquist. &
  33 Delegacias de Lisboa (2000-2002). &
  Nº de policiais; Custo do trabalho; nº de veículos; outros custos; roubos; furtos; roubos de veículos; e crimes relacionados a drogas. &
  Esclarecimento de roubos e furtos;  esclarecimentode roubos de  veículos;  esclarecimento de crimes envolvendo drogas;  Operaçõesde Busca;  operações de trânsito e multas.  \\ \hline
Barros (2007) &
  DEA-BCC, DEA-CCR e Modelo Tobit no 2º Estágio. &
  Os mesmos de Barros (2006). &
  Os mesmos de Barros (2006). &
  Os mesmos de Barros (2006).  \\ \hline
Gárcia-Sánchez (2007) &
  DEA-CCR e modelo  Tobit no segundo estágio. &
  52 capitais provinciais na Espanha (1999). &
  Crimes e delitos leves. &
  Número de indivíduos  presos em crimes; número de indivíduos  presos em delitos leves  \\ \hline
Gárcia-Sánchez (2009) &
  DEA-BCC. &
  113 cidades na Espanha (2000). &
  Total de funcionários e nº de veículos. &
  Segurança pública; Segurança na estrada.  \\ \hline
Gárcia-Sánchez et. al. (2013) &
  DEA-BCC com cálculo de Índices de Malmquist. &
  Unidades policiais de províncias na Espanha  (2001-2006). &
  Nº de forças de seguranças por província. &
  Nº de crimes solucionados  sobre de crimes; crimes contra pessoas;  crimes contra a liberdade sexual;  crimes contra a segurança pública.  \\ \hline
Haddad et. al. (2013) &
  DEA-CCR regressão no 2º Estágio (fatores exógenos). &
  13 delegacias no sul de Israel, (2008-2011). &
  nsumos de crimes; insumos operacionais; e insumos regionais. &
  Taxa anual de esclarecimentos de crimes contra a propriedade; nº de casos envolvendo embriaguez esclarecidos; nº relatórios de tráfego.  \\ \hline
Poveda et. al. (2019) &
  DEA e GMM. &
  20 departamentos na Colombia (2001-2015). &
  Nível de educação; nº de criminosos presos;  nº de policiais. &
  Taxa de homicídios; nível de corrupção.  \\ \hline
Alda et. al. (2020) &
  Modelo fronteira parcial de ordem m, condicional e incondicional. &
  1634 forças policiais municipais no México, (2015). &
  Nº de policiais; nº de viaturas policiais; tecnologia disponível. &
  Nº de crimes impedidos  \\ \hline
\end{xltabular}
\end{landscape}
%\fonte{Elaboração do autor a partir dos estudos citados.}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

After one year ...

- Now, when the `tabularray` package is already well known, let exploit it in writing OP table.
- Table is quite huge, so it is not possible to fit it on one page even when are used `\footnotesize` font size (smaller fonts are unreadable small), so a long table is option to go.
- For long tables is in `tabularray` package defined `longtblr` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm, showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Literatura internacional pertinente ao tema.},
  label = {quad:quadro},
                ]{%
        rowhead = 1,
        hlines, vlines,
        colspec = { X[0.7,l]*{4}{X[j]} },
        colsep  = 3pt,
        rowsep  = 1pt,
        rows    = {font=\small},
        row{1}  = {font=\small\bfseries, c, m}
             }
Autor e ano
    &   Método
        &   Recorte espacial e temporal
            &   Insumos
                &   Produtos    \\ 
 DEA-CCR. 
    &   41 unidades policiais da Inglaterra e do País de Gales, (1992-1993). 
        &   N° de policias empregados; n° de crimes violentos; roubos; outros crimes. 
            &   Taxa de esclarecimentos de crimes violentos; taxa de esclarecimentos de roubos; taxa de esclarecimentos de outros crimes registrados.  
                                \\ 
Carrington et. al. (1997) 
    &   DEA-CCR e DEA-BCC. Modelo de dois estágios com modelo Tobit. 
        &   163 unidades policiais em Nova Gales do Sul, Austrália, (1994- 1995). 
            &   N° de policiais; n° de voluntários civis; n° de viaturas policiais. 
                &   N° de crimes; n° de prisões; n° de intimações; n° de acidentes de carros graves; Km’s percorridos pelas viaturas policias.  
                                \\ 
Drake e Simper (2000)
    &   DEA e análise múltipla discriminante. 
        &   Forças policiais metropolitana da Inglaterra e de Gales, (1992-1997). 
            &   Custo de emprego; despesas relacionadas a instalações; despesas relacionadas a transporte; custos de capital.  
                &   Taxa de esclarecimento; o nº total de crimes de tráfico; nº de testes de bafômetro realizados.
                                \\
Drake e Simper (2001) 
    &   DEA (eficiência geral,  eficiência técnica e eficiência de escala). 
        &   39 Unidades Policiais da Inglaterra e País de Gales (1996-1999). 
            &   Os mesmos de Drake e Simper (2000). 
                &   Os mesmos de Drake e Simper (2000).  
                    \\
Sun (2002) 
    &   DEA. No segundo estágio, múltiplas regressões para empregar uma análise dos fatores externos.
        &   14 delegacias municipais de Taipei, Taiwan (1994-1996). 
            &   Nº policiais; roubos; nº crimes violentos; outros crimes. 
                &   Esclarecimentos de roubos;  esclarecimentos de crimes violentos; esclarecimentos de outros crimes.  
                    \\ 
Diez-Ticio e Mancebon (2002) 
    &   DEA-BCC e modelo TMM. 
        &   47 Unidades Policiais da Espanha (1995). 
            &   Nº de policiais; Nº de veículos; Inverso da População. 
                &   Taxa de esclarecimento de crimes  contra a propriedade;  taxa de esclarecimento de crimes violents .  
                    \\
Drake e Simper (2003) 
    &   DEA-CCR, SFA,  SDEA e modelo Tobit no segundo estágio. 
        &   42 Unidades Policiais da Inglaterra e País de Gales (1996-1999). 
            &   Os mesmos de Drake e Simper (2000). 
                &   Os mesmos de Drake e Simper (2000).  
                    \\
Barros e Alves (2005) 
    &   SFA (Custo), com controle para variáveis ambientais. 
        &   33 Delegacias de Lisboa (1999-2003).
            &   Custo Operacional; fator Trabalho (razão salário-trabalhadores); fator Capital 1 (razão custo de trasnportes-nº carros); fator Capital 2 (razão custo das instalações -população).
                &   esclarecimentocrimes de roubos e furtos; esclarecimento de roubos  e furtos de veículos;   esclarecimentode crimes envolvendo drogas.  
                    \\
Drake e Simper (2005) 
    &   DEA-BCC e  Fronteira de distância de produto estocástica. 
        &   293 Distritos Policiais da Inglaterra e Paíse de Gales (2001-2002). 
            &   6 tipos de crimes diferentes. 
                &   Esclarecimentos de 6 tipos de  crimes diferentes.  
                    \\
Barros (2006) 
    &   DEA-BCC com cálculo de Índices de Malmquist. 
        &   33 Delegacias de Lisboa (2000-2002). 
            &   Nº de policiais; Custo do trabalho; nº de veículos; outros custos; roubos; furtos; roubos de veículos; e crimes relacionados a drogas.
                &   Esclarecimento de roubos e furtos;  esclarecimentode roubos de  veículos;  esclarecimento de crimes envolvendo drogas;  Operaçõesde Busca;  operações de trânsito e multas.  
                    \\
Barros (2007) 
    &   DEA-BCC, DEA-CCR e Modelo Tobit no 2º Estágio. 
        &   Os mesmos de Barros (2006). 
            &   Os mesmos de Barros (2006). 
                &   Os mesmos de Barros (2006).  
                    \\
Gárcia-Sánchez (2007) 
    &   DEA-CCR e modelo  Tobit no segundo estágio. 
        &   52 capitais provinciais na Espanha (1999). 
            &   Crimes e delitos leves. 
                &   Número de indivíduos  presos em crimes; número de indivíduos  presos em delitos leves
                    \\ 
Gárcia-Sánchez (2009) 
    &   DEA-BCC. 
        &   113 cidades na Espanha (2000). 
            &   Total de funcionários e nº de veículos. 
                &   Segurança pública; Segurança na estrada.  
                    \\
Gárcia-Sánchez et. al. (2013) 
    &  DEA-BCC com cálculo de Índices de Malmquist. 
        &   Unidades policiais de províncias na Espanha  (2001-2006). 
            &   Nº de forças de seguranças por província. 
                &     Nº de crimes solucionados  sobre de crimes; crimes contra pessoas;  crimes contra a liberdade sexual;  crimes contra a segurança pública.
                    \\ 
Haddad et. al. (2013) 
    &   DEA-CCR regressão no 2º Estágio (fatores exógenos). 
        &   13 delegacias no sul de Israel, (2008-2011). 
                &   nsumos de crimes; insumos operacionais; e insumos regionais. 
                    &   Taxa anual de esclarecimentos de crimes contra a propriedade; nº de casos envolvendo embriaguez esclarecidos; nº relatórios de tráfego.  
                        \\ 
Poveda et. al. (2019) 
    &   DEA e GMM.
        &   20 departamentos na Colombia (2001-2015).
                &   Nível de educação; nº de criminosos presos;  nº de policiais.
                    &   Taxa de homicídios; nível de corrupção.  
                        \\
Alda et. al. (2020) 
    &   Modelo fronteira parcial de ordem m, condicional e incondicional. 
        &   1634 forças policiais municipais no México, (2015). 
            &   Nº de policiais; nº de viaturas policiais; tecnologia disponível. 
                &   Nº de crimes impedidos  
                    \\  
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Zarko, this only gets better !!

Comment: Dear @VitorDeVasconcelosLima, site has policy that we express our thankfulness by voting (by clicking on up pen at top left side of answer). If solution proposed in received answer you use in your project, you should consider to accept them by clicking on the check mark at the top left side of this answer. By this you inform people here, that your problem is solved  .  As I see, so far you not accept any of received answers .

Comment: Sorry, zarko, I hadn't thought of that. Sorry for the mistake, that won't happen again.

Comment: @VitorDeVasconcelosLima, you can correct this just now! You not need to wait on your new question .

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, but I couldn't find the pen. I wanted to select your answer as the best.

Comment: @VitorDeVasconcelosLima, pen? huh, I forgot that was not so long ago it was replaced by (up) triangle. Sorry for my forgetfulness ...

Comment: it says that i need a minimun of 15 points of reputation to up vote

Comment: @VitorDeVasconcelosLima, now you have more than 15 pints. However, you can (regardless zo your reputation) accept one of received answers (the one which you liked most). As I already mentioned on one my previous coment.