# How to fit a table that is too tall and tool wide in a page?

Tags: tables

Well, I want to know if its possible to plot a table that is too wide and to tall in a page. My table is this one:

```
\begin{quadro}[H]
\caption{\textbf{Literatura internacional pertinente ao tema.}}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Autor e ano} &
  \textbf{Método} &
  \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Recorte espacial e\\ temporal\end{tabular}} &
  \textbf{Insumos} &
  \textbf{Produtos} \\ \hline
Thanassoulis (1995) &
  DEA-CCR. &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}41 unidades policiais\\ da Inglaterra e do País\\ de Gales, (1992-1993).\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}N° de policias\\ empregados; n° de\\ crimes violentos;\\ roubos; outros crimes.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Taxa de esclarecimentos de\\ crimes violentos; taxa\\ de esclarecimentos de\\ roubos; taxa de\\ esclarecimentos de\\ outros crimes\\ registrados.\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Carrington et. al.\\ (1997)\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DEA-CCR e DEA-BCC. Modelo de dois\\ estágios com modelo\\ Tobit.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}163 unidades policiais\\ em Nova Gales do\\ Sul, Austrália, (1994-\\ 1995).\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}N° de policiais; n° de\\ voluntários civis; n°\\ de viaturas policiais.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}N° de crimes; n° de prisões; n° de\\ intimações; n° de\\ acidentes de carros\\ graves; Km’s\\ percorridos pelas\\ viaturas policias.\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Drake e Simper\\ (2000)\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DEA e análise\\ múltipla\\ discriminante.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Forças policiais\\ metropolitana da\\ Inglaterra e de Gales,\\ (1992-1997).\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Custo de emprego; despesas relacionadas\\ a instalações; despesas\\ relacionadas a\\ transporte; custos de\\ capital.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Taxa de esclarecimento; o nº\\ total de crimes de\\ tráfico; nº de testes de\\ bafômetro realizados.\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Drake e Simper\\ (2001)\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DEA (eficiência geral, \\ eficiência técnica e eficiência de escala).\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}39 Unidades Policiais\\ da Inglaterra e País de\\ Gales (1996-1999).\end{tabular} &
  Os mesmos de Drake e Simper (2000). &
  Os mesmos de Drake e Simper (2000). \\ \hline
Sun (2002) &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DEA. No segundo\\ estágio, múltiplas\\ regressões para\\ empregar uma análise\\ dos fatores externos.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}14 delegacias\\ municipais de Taipei,\\ Taiwan (1994-1996).\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Nº policiais; roubos; nº crimes violentos;\\ outros crimes.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Esclarecimentos de roubos; \\ esclarecimentos de\\ crimes violentos;\\ esclarecimentos de\\ outros crimes.\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Diez-Ticio e\\ Mancebon\\ (2002)\end{tabular} &
  DEA-BCC e modelo TMM. &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}47 Unidades Policiais\\ da Espanha (1995).\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Nº de policiais; Nº de veículos; Inverso\\ da População.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Taxa de esclarecimento de crimes\\  contra a propriedade; \\ taxa de esclarecimento de crimes violents .\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Drake e Simper\\ (2003)\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DEA-CCR, SFA, \\ SDEA e modelo Tobit no segundo estágio.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}42 Unidades Policiais\\ da Inglaterra e País de\\ Gales (1996-1999).\end{tabular} &
  Os mesmos de Drake e Simper (2000). &
  Os mesmos de Drake e Simper (2000). \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Barros e Alves\\ (2005)\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}SFA (Custo), com\\ controle para variáveis\\ ambientais.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}33 Delegacias de\\ Lisboa (1999-2003).\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Custo Operacional; fator Trabalho\\ (razão salário-trabalhadores); fator Capital 1\\ (razão custo de trasnportes-n º carros); fator\\ capital 2 (razão custo das instalações -população).\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}esclarecimentocrimes de \\ roubos e furtos;\\ esclarecimento de roubos\\  e furtos de veículos; \\  esclarecimentode crimes\\ envolvendo drogas.\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Drake e Simper\\ (2005)\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DEA-BCC e\\  Fronteira de distância de produto estocástica.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}293 Distritos Policiais\\ da Inglaterra e Paíse de\\ Gales (2001-2002).\end{tabular} &
  6 tipos de crimes diferentes. &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Esclarecimentos de 6 tipos de\\  crimes diferentes.\end{tabular} \\ \hline
Barros (2006) &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DEA-BCC com cálculo de\\ Índices de Malmquist.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}33 Delegacias de\\ Lisboa (2000-2002).\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Nº de policiais; Custo do trabalho; nº\\ de veículos; outros custos; roubos;\\ furtos; roubos de veículos; e crimes\\ relacionados a drogas.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Esclarecimento de roubos e furtos; \\ esclarecimentode roubos de \\ veículos;  esclarecimento\\ de crimes envolvendo drogas; \\ Operaçõesde Busca;\\  operações de trânsito e multas.\end{tabular} \\ \hline
Barros (2007) &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DEA-BCC, DEA-CCR e Modelo Tobit no\\ 2º Estágio.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Os mesmos de Barros\\ (2006).\end{tabular} &
  Os mesmos de Barros (2006). &
  Os mesmos de Barros (2006). \\ \hline
Gárcia-Sánchez (2007) &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DEA-CCR e modelo \\ Tobit no segundo estágio.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}52 capitais provinciais na Espanha\\ (1999).\end{tabular} &
  Crimes e delitos leves. &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Número de indivíduos\\  presos em crimes;\\ número de indivíduos \\ presos em delitos leves\end{tabular} \\ \hline
Gárcia-Sánchez (2009) &
  DEA-BCC. &
  113 cidades na Espanha (2000). &
  Total de funcionários e nº de veículos. &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Segurança pública;\\ Segurança na estrada.\end{tabular} \\ \hline
Gárcia-Sánchez et. al. (2013) &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DEA-BCC com cálculo de\\ Índices de Malmquist.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Unidades policiais de províncias na Espanha \\ (2001-2006).\end{tabular} &
  Nº de forças de seguranças por província. &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Nº de crimes solucionados \\ sobre de crimes;\\ crimes contra pessoas; \\ crimes contra a liberdade sexual; \\ crimes contra a segurança pública.\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Haddad et. al.\\ (2013)\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DEA-CCR regressão no 2º\\ Estágio (fatores exógenos).\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}13 delegacias no sul\\ de Israel, (2008-2011).\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}nsumos de crimes;\\ insumos operacionais;\\ e insumos regionais.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Taxa anual de\\ esclarecimentos de\\ crimes contra a\\ propriedade; nº de\\ casos envolvendo\\ embriaguez\\ esclarecidos; nº\\ relatórios de tráfego.\end{tabular} \\ \hline
Poveda et. al. (2019) &
  DEA e GMM. &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}20 departamentos na Colombia\\ (2001-2015).\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Nível de educação;\\ nº de criminosos presos; \\ nº de policiais.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Taxa de homicídios;\\ nível de corrupção.\end{tabular} \\ \hline
Alda et. al. (2020) &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Modelo fronteira\\ parcial de ordem m,\\ condicional e\\ incondicional.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}1634 forças policiais\\ municipais no\\ México, (2015).\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Nº de policiais; nº de\\ viaturas policiais;\\ tecnologia disponível.\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Nº de crimes\\ impedidos\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\fonte{Elaboração do autor a partir dos estudos citados.}
\label{quad:quadro}
\end{quadro}
```

Output:
[image]

Ps: Sorry for being anoying with a lot of questions, but i'm new in latex and have a couple months to finish my thesis.

Comment: Thanks @Werner. Nope.

Comment: What do you mean by "plot a table"?

Comment: Also, you mention that the suggested duplicate doesn't help. Have you tried everything? Surely the `\resizebox` option would work. If not, why not?

Comment: When a table almost fits in the text area one can do several things to reduce some wasted space in the table as in the suggested link. In a case like this, that table hardly fit is a landscape page even with  `\tiny` font and only 1.5 cm margins, the only relevant that you can do is redesign the table and reduce the contents, or better no use a table but other format, as a list, or use `\resizebox` as Werner said, but providing with your thesis   hand magnifying glasses.

Comment: @Werner, @Fran: In a previous version of the table, the OP already used `adjustbox` in order to squeeze the table into the margins but then was unsatisfied with the resulting font size: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/577445/134144

Comment: The general mechanisms suggested in the answers to the general "too wide" question are all applicable here. If you want specific help with this specific table then you need to give more information. No one can run the example or tell you how to make it fit in the page width. As you have not defined `quadro` and have not said how wide your page is. Please always make your code examples complete small documents that produce the image shown, so people can debug and test answers.

Comment: while js bibra's answer below helps with the formatting and the code to lay out this table, I'd start by looking at the content.  First: is a table the right way to show such large quantities of information (or could the table summarise to allow comparison, with a paragraph of text in the body for each line, to give more detail).  Second: can the information be given more concisely - the tersest wording you can, more abbreviations explained just below the table, etc.  I know no Portuguese so can't offer deeper suggestions

Comment: First of all, thanks to everyone who responded, I thank you from the heart,
I apologize if I was not clear or if I ignored the suggestions, I looked at them, but I did not understand correctly, I think because I am new to latex, as I said.
There are other tables (tables) in the thesis. The objective is to summarize the contributions in a table, contributions that are in the text.
Once again, thank you very much, I will try to read about my problem and try to reverse engineer the @js briba table.

Answer (score 2):

I have only formatted the header and the first row

Using `tabularx` the third and fourth column are kept left aligned/ ragged right (using the Y type of column) whereas the fifth column is kept center aligned (using the Z type column)

You may like to copy across the same formatting to the remaining rows

Using left aligned or centering in the columns is a choice for the OP -- `quadro` has not been defined hence omitted

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}


\usepackage{tabularx}  % for 'tabularx' environment and 'X' column type
\usepackage{ragged2e}  % for '\RaggedRight' macro (allows hyphenation)
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X} 
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 
\usepackage{booktabs}  % for \toprule, \midrule, and \bottomrule macros 

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} c c Y Y Z @{}} % use 'Y' for first column
            \toprule
            
            \textbf{Autor e ano} &
            \textbf{Método} &
            \textbf{Recorte espacial e temporal} &
            \textbf{Insumos} &
            \textbf{Produtos} 
            \\ \midrule
            Thanassoulis (1995) &
            DEA-CCR. &
            {41 unidades policiais da Inglaterra e do País de Gales, (1992-1993)} &
            {N° de policias empregados; n° de crimes violentos; roubos; outros crimes}&
            {Taxa de esclarecimentos de crimes violentos; taxa de esclarecimentos de roubos; taxa de esclarecimentos de outros crimes registrados}\\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd also put "Autor" on one line and "e ano" underneath, and the same with the contents of that column.  This would give more width for the others and reduce the need for hyphenation. At the moment the column with the least content is the widest.  You could go further and stack the "Método" under that, especially if you abbreviated it and/or used table notes to allow a more compressed description.  But I'd rotate the page before doing that

Comment: quite true -- since the breaks are in a language which is foreign to me I have not meddled lest the meaning of some word changes